# rails: method_missing error but respond_to? results in true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

One of my rspec controller tests is failing with
undefined method `current_user' for #<#:0x007fbf18554608>

This is strange because the line where the error occurs looks like this:

```
h.respond_to?(:current_user) ? h.current_user : nil) : 0
```

Before I access current_user, I check its presence with respond_to?

When I run the tests with a debugger this happens:

```
(byebug) dh.respond_to?(:current_user)
true
(byebug) dh.current_user
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `current_user' for #<#         <Class:0x007f9bfed902f0>:0x007f9bf346fc08>

nil
```

How is it possible that the Object answers to respond_to?(:current_user) with true and returns a no method error when I try to call the method?

It also very difficult to create a minimal example that fails, because the tests are only failing im I run the complete suite. Running the failing tests standalone succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your ruby version must be less than Ruby 2.0. Till Ruby 1.9, respond_to? method returns true for protected and private methods. But when a protected or private method is invoked on a object, that raises NoMethodError.

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/09/07/protected-methods-and-ruby-2-0.html

In your case, current user must be either private or protected method.

Comment: Interesting. I will check this tommorow in the office. Thanks! But I'm sure that we are using ruby > 2.1